# Android EditText setText cause softkeyboard to freeze

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am having a problem with the `EditText`.

I have implemented a `TextWatcher` and I check every time in `afterTextChanged` to highlight some specific keywords in an `AsyncTask` and set the text in `onPostExcute`(I only touch the UI here), but the soft keyboard freeze when `setText` was called in `onPostExcute`(the app didn't freeze).

```
public class AsyncHighLight extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] p1){
        return SyntaxHighlighter.getInstance(MainActivity.this).highlight(p1[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        et.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
    }
}
```

The highlight code here

```
public String highlight(String s){
    String newString = s;
    newString = newString.replace("\n","<br>");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < currentLang.keyword.length ; i ++){
        newString = newString.replace(currentLang.keyword[i],warpColorTag(currentLang.keyword[i]));
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Just return the result directly and apply et.settext() inside activity scope only

Comment: @Haroon you mean not to set it in onPostExecute? I will try

Comment: @Haroon if i dont use async task , the ui freeze

Comment: Soft keyboard freezez OR lags for some time ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna the keyboard freeze until i close everything

Comment: @benny Good to know you solved it.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna thank you too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write the logic of terminate the afterTextChange() method of TextWatcher as whenever the text got change afterTextChange() will gets called and every time afterTextChange() gets called you highlight some specific keywords in an AsyncTask and again in onPostExecute() will gets called and it will setText() again. SO you have to find the way of terminating the afterTextChange() logic. For better help please post TextWatcher code too.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to tha reason that as soon as you settext in onpostexecute, textchange event fires again and it goes into async task again thus it goes into a infinite loop. 
You should use a boolean to trace whether the event is genrated from onpostexecute or by keyboard input